# Play 2.7 http request post request

Tags: java, rest, playframework

I am trying to do post request in play framework. Below is my sample code

routes.conf:

```
POST  /movies/add        controllers.MovieController.add()
```

controller:

```
public Result add(Request request) { 
    System.out.println("BODY:::"+request.body().toString());
    return ok();
}
```

I get below error

```
not enough arguments for method add: (x$1: play.mvc.Http.Request)play.mvc.Result.
```

What am i missing here to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your add method is expecting a request object but its not in the route.  I based this on the post example in the link below.

`POST  /movies/add          controllers.MovieController.add(request: Request)`

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/JavaFileUpload#Uploading-files-in-a-form-using-multipart/form-data